# Automatically generate the input value based on current system time

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a production recording system. What I want is that to automatically generate the input in "hour" based on the current system time. For example if the system time is in between 7.00 am and 7.15 am, the "hour" should be 1.Like that it should continue. I have written the following code but seems like it is wrong.Can anyone give me suggestions for that?

```
<?php
      $sql="SELECT CURTIME() AS Time";
      $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $time=$row['Time'];

    }
    if("07:00:00"<="$time"<="07:15:00"){
  echo "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='hour' value='1' readonly >";

    }
       ?>
```

Comment: Why are you getting the current system time from a database query rather than using `time()` or if you want datetime `date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time())`?

Comment: From that, can i do the above comparison in the if condition?

Comment: What if it's 6.35am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to manipulate times using timestamps. You can set the start and end times and then do a simple conditional to display the form element you want to display.

```
$current_time = time();
$start = strtotime("07:00:00");
$end = strtotime("07:15:00");

if ($current_time > $start && $current_time < $end)
{
   echo "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='hour' value='1' readonly >";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution which helped me

```
<?php

 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Colombo");
 $current_time=date('H:i:s', time());

 $time1 ="06:00:00";
 $time2 ="07:15:00";

 if ($current_time > $time1 && $current_time < $time2)
      {
      echo "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='hour' value='1' readonly >";
      }
  <?
```